# TypeError : count() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python, django, list, django-rest-framework

i am getting TypeError: `count() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)`.

it would be great if anybody could figure out where i am doing thing wrong. thank you so much in advance.

```
class CommentsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comment_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Comments
        fields = [
            "id", "title", "name", "subject", "comment_count",
        ]

    def get_comment_count(self, obj):
        return obj.subject.count()
```

Comment: what type is "subject" ?

Comment: Is subject a list type of object? in that case you need to add one more argument as what character do you need to count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation does not make sense. I think you are trying to get count of all the `Comments` object, but here you are trying to count subject, probably that is a string or a list. On them, count works like this:

```
IN  >> "aaaaa".count('a')
OUT >> 5
IN  >> [1,2,3,4].count(1)
OUT >> 1
```

Now, to fix your problem, we need to understand what you want to achieve here. If you want to get count of comments for a particular post, then you can try like this:

If you have a model like this:

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
```

Then you can take this approach:

```
def get_comment_count(self, obj):
    return obj.post.comments_set.count()
```

This is [`count()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.count) function from Django queryset. And `obj.post.comments_set` will return a queryset(for having a reverse relationship). If you have defined `related_name="post_comments"`([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)), then it will become `obj.post.post_comments.count()`.

Answer (score 1):

You may check the function description [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-function-count/#:%7E:text=count()%20is%20an%20inbuilt,given%20object%20occurs%20in%20list.)

It counts the occurrence of an object in a list, so you need to pass an object as a parameter to count() function, and apply this on a list.

Also, it would be better if you give a sample program that you got the error.

Answer (score 1):

`count()` requires exactly one argument and returns the number of instances of the provided argument in the list.

If you just want to count number of elements in a list, use:

```
return len(obj.subject)
```

Answer (score 1):

`count` requires an argument. It returns the number of instances of a particular item in a list.

```
    l=[1,2,5,4,5,6,7,10]
    l.count(5)
    2
```

`2` here is the number of `5`s in the list.